# Event trigger (button) opening multiple instances of same window

Tags: c#, wpf, button, multiple-instances

In my WPF application, I have a main window (Branch.xaml) which has a button that will open an other window (Location.xaml). Once this Location window is open, how do I prevent another instance of this Location window from opening, when the user clicks the same button again?

Or how can I re-focus the same open window, when the user clicks the button again?

The button click code is auto-generated code when you double-click on a button in xaml.

In the "Branch.xaml.cs" file, the code for button click is as follows:

```
private void rbtn_Location_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Location location = new Location(); 
    location.Show(); 
}
```

Location is a custom class which opens a window with 3 list boxes

Thanks, any help is appreciated.
I'm using WPF application on C# 4.0 & Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: What is the code for your Click event?

Comment: @Mark: It is an auto-generated code when you double-click on a button in xaml.
In the "Branch.xaml.cs" file, the code for button click is as follows:


private void rbtn_Location_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Location location = new Location();
            location.Show();
        }


Location is a custom class which opens a window with 3 list boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a field in your main window which holds a reference to the location window if there is any, in the button click handler check if the field is null and if it is create a new window and store it in the field, if not call `Activate` on the window in the field. You also would have to subscribe to the `Closed` event of the location window to clear out the reference again when the location window is gone.

**Edit:** Concrete example:

```
private LocationWindow locationWindow;
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (locationWindow == null)
    {
        locationWindow = new LocationWindow();
        locationWindow.Closed += (s, _) => locationWindow = null;
        locationWindow.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        locationWindow.Activate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. How would I create a reference to a window? I apologize for the beginner question. Would you mind explaining a bit further, your above answer. Thanks. Much appreciated.

Comment: @PaulEngels: You use a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) or a [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx), in the above example i use a field.

Comment: @ H.B. : Thank you so much. You just saved me a lot of time. I sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**Application.Current.Windows** collection holds reference for all windows for current **AppDomain**. You can check for your window in that collection and if it founds your window then call **Activate** for that window else **create new Window**. This will get you going -

```
private void rbtn_Location_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Window window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().Where(win => win.Name == "LocationWindow").FirstOrDefault();
    if(window == null)
    {
       Location location = new Location(); 
       location.Show(); 
    }
    else
    {
       window.Activate();  
    }
}
```

Make sure you provide your window a `x:Name` as LocationWindow to make it work.

```
<Window x:Name="LocationWindow">
</Window>
```

Also include namespace `System.Linq` in your code behind.

Comment: @ RV1987: Thank you. This snippet of code works as well. Much appreciate it.